# Why int main() returns with an value of unsigned char range?

Tags: c++, c++11, program-entry-point

Good night,

Take as example the follow program:

```cpp
int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Everything works fine and I get the follow message on the console indicating that the program exited with code 0:

```
hh:mm:ss: /path/to/executable exited with code 0
```

Now when I try this:

```cpp
int main()
{
    return -1;
}
```

I get the same message, except that it says that I exited with code 255 (instead of -1):

```
hh:mm:ss: /path/to/executable exited with code 255
```

Now switching to `return 256` it says that the program `exited with code 0`, which make me think that it should be actually `unsigned char main()` instead of `int main()`, since that the return type behaves like a `unsigned char` type.

Why does that happen?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is dependent on your OS.  The C++ standard says that `main` returns `int`, but if your OS doesn't want to use all those bits, that's up to it.

Comment: The standard only says that the function returns `int`.   It doesn't specify what the host system does with that return value - so the host system can do what it likes.

Comment: The only values an implementation is required to support are zero and EXIT_FAILURE. Anything else is optional.

Comment: @RaymondChen — there’s also `EXIT_SUCCESS`.

Comment: @PeteBecker EXIT_SUCCESS is defined to be zero

Comment: @RaymondChen -- the definition of `EXIT_SUCCESS` is up to the implementation. It's not required to be 0. Both `return EXIT_SUCCESS;` and `return 0;` return an exit code that indicates success. On a system where that code should be something other than 0, `EXIT_SUCCESS` can simply be that value. In that case, the wrapper code that calls `main` would have to look for a 0 return value from `main` and return the appropriate success code to the OS.

Comment: @PeteBecker thanks for the clarification. I misread "0 or EXIT_SUCCESS" as "0,also known as ERROR_SUCCESS".